# Discrete logarithm problem particularly hard for Schnorr groups?

Tags: discrete-logarithm, schnorr-signature, schnorr-identification

The [Wikipedia article on Discrete Logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm#Cryptography) just states without source:

> In some cases (e.g. large prime order subgroups of groups ($\mathbb{Z}_p)^×$) there is not only no efficient algorithm known for the worst case, but the average-case complexity can be shown to be about as hard as the worst case using random self-reducibility.

To my understanding "large prime order subgroups of groups ($\mathbb{Z}_p)^×$" are also known as [Schnorr groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnorr_group). But apparently not everybody calls them that (?).

So where would I find a (citable) proof that the discrete logarithm problem is (assumed to be) hard for elements of a Schnorr group?

This is probably related to [Why does Schnorr's Digital Signature scheme necessitate two prime numbers?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5504/why-does-schnorrs-digital-signature-scheme-necessitate-two-prime-numbers/), which would be my next question. The answer given there may be correct but also without a citable source...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know an exact citable source.

However the rationale is roughly the following:

The Decisional Diffie-Hellman Problem (DDHP) is not hard in $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ since the Legendre symbol leaks the parity of the discrete log (DLOG) [1 section 5.1.2, 2]. You can use this fact to build an efficient algorithm to distinguish between Diffie-Hellman and non Diffie Hellman tuples [3 section 6.6]. 
Another reason is the existence of the Pohlig - Hellman Algorithm [1].

Note that the semantic security of the ElGamal cryptosystem rests on the DDHP problem, which is believed to be easier than the DLOG problem.

References:

[1]Cryptography: Theory and Practice by Douglas Stinson

[2] [Finding $x$'s parity in the discrete log problem](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/22830/finding-xs-parity-in-the-discrete-log-problem)

[3] https://crypto.di.uoa.gr/class/Kryptographia/Semeioseis_files/Cryptograph_Primitives_and_Protocols.pdf

Comment: But why does the order need to be prime? What is the problem if the order of the group was not prime?

Comment: Because if it is not prime, then the chinese remainder theorem through the Pohlig Hellman algorithm will effectively reduce it to (smaller) prime order subgroups. So I guess with prime orders you can estimate exactly the difficulty.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out! This is really appreciated.